# Calculation equivalence in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am calculating a log return series for a study on financial data.

By the laws of logarithms `log(p_t/p_t-1)` is the same as `log(p_t) - log(p_t-1)`.

I calculate two different series that should be the same...

`r = log(price(2:end)) - log(price(1:(end - 1)));`

`r1 = log(price(2:end))./price(1:(end - 1));`

Out of curiosity I decided to check:

`r1 == r`

and I get a *TON* of 0's in the result array.

Is there some reason for this? These two should be absolutely equivalent. I wouldn't think weird floating point things would be a problem here, and if they were a problem they'd effect both vectors equally.

What is going on here?

Comment: You're probably seeing the limitations of numerical precision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)

Comment: For floating point values, equality check must implement a tolerance: eq = abs(a - b) <= eps(max(abs(a), abs(b)));

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo Ah I see, isn't it strange that it wouldn't truncate/round all the numbers the same?

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo: nice comment.

Comment: @rec: using TommasoBelluzzo suggestion you should have all ones (to be on the safe side I would even check for a bigger epsilon).

Comment: @rec It isn't strange because the two numbers are computed in different ways meaning different rounding errors are introduced during intermediate computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong in the second equation, but you will still get floating point differences.

```
r = log(price(2:end)) - log(price(1:(end - 1)));

r1 = log(price(2:end)./price(1:(end - 1)));
```